# Add Missing Date Index with default values

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a pandas dataframe with an index representing the data (in monthly format) and multiple columns with numeric data. Min Example is below:

```
 dict1 = [{'var0': 45, 'var1': 3, 'var2': 2},
     {'var0': 32, 'var1': 4, 'var2': 4},
     {'var0': 23, 'var1': 5, 'var2': 8},
     {'var0': 22, 'var1': 2, 'var2': 12},]
 df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=['2016-08', '2016-09','2016-11','2016-12'])
```

Some of the months are missing however, that is, notice how the index jumps from Sep to Nov. I would like to fill all of the missing months such that the new dataframe contains additional rows with that month as an index and zeros in the respective row, that is:

```
  dict1 = [{'var0': 45, 'var1': 3, 'var2': 2},
     {'var0': 32, 'var1': 4, 'var2': 4},
     {'var0': 23, 'var1': 5, 'var2': 8},
     {'var0':  0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 0},
     {'var0': 22, 'var1': 2, 'var2': 12},]
  df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=['2016-08'', '2016-09', '2016-09','2016-11','2016-12'])
```

Can anyone recommend an approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` and use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.asfreq('MS', fill_value=0)
```

Or [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`pandas.date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html):

```
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='MS'), fill_value=0)

print(df)
            var0  var1  var2
2016-08-01    45     3     2
2016-09-01    32     4     4
2016-10-01     0     0     0
2016-11-01    23     5     8
2016-12-01    22     2    12
```

Solution with `month period` - creating [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) with [`pandas.period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.period_range.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_period('M')
df = df.reindex(pd.period_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max(), freq='M'), fill_value=0)
print(df)
         var0  var1  var2
2016-08    45     3     2
2016-09    32     4     4
2016-10     0     0     0
2016-11    23     5     8
2016-12    22     2    12
```

Last if necessary convert to strings `YY-MM` add [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m')
print(df)
         var0  var1  var2
2016-08    45     3     2
2016-09    32     4     4
2016-10     0     0     0
2016-11    23     5     8
2016-12    22     2    12
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much!! Thanks also for the multiple approaches, will add that to my cheat sheet.